# How to use the CD command in a bash scipt?

Tags: windows, command-line, scripting

I have a bash script that looks like the below. When I run it in the terminal, it just leaves a blank space. I want to be able to CD into this different location to get to the file I need OR ALTERNATIVELY is there a way of getting a file from a different location?

```
#!/bin/bash
# My first script

alias location="cd C:/Users/A591024/AppData/Local/Temp/TD_80/hq**/1212*1212/R*****"
```

do I maybe need to say something like "run location" underneath?

the final goal is to be able to get to a file inside the R****** folder and open up that file inside the window and try and grep from that..

also this is being done inside windows command line not linux

Comment: this looks ok, only that the alias will just persist during the execution time of the script. You probably want to run this `alias location="cd ..."` in your main shell, so that you can reuse it later. Also, try to explain what is your final goal, because it is not very clear.

Comment: @fedorqui made edits for the final goal.

Comment: OK, why are you making an alias?  An alias creates a new command that you can type at the prompt.

If you just want to cd into a directory, just cd into that directory.

I'm still confused by what you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe you should post your idea of what a successful session would look like assuming your script already worked?

Comment: @MarkReed I have edited my question to show the final goal. I created an alias because when I was doing my research on this problem that was the most common solution. But to summarize, all I want to do is run a script that will get a file from the path given and then will open this file and then I will use the grep command to pull stuff out. surely it must be simple to run a script in one location and pull out information elsewhere...

Comment: I would like to see, verbatim, what you expect to be able to type, and what you expect the output to be. If you're using grep to search through a file, the only "open a file" that happens is inside the grep program.  From bash, you just do `grep whatever /path/to/file` and you're done.  It's one line.

Comment: i have sorted this now as i am using a .bat file.
I have another query though. Why will this not work 128100.html > 128100.xls? i am trying to push data from a .html file and create an excel file with that data in?

Comment: @MarkReed anyway to private message you as I reckon you will know the answer to his and I really need to solve it soon

Answer (score 1):

If you run this script, then Linux will create a new shell for you. The new shell will execute the `alias` command. Since there are no more commands after that, the new shell will terminate.

Since the `alias` command is executed in a new shell (or subshell), your current shell isn't modified. Hence, after the script ends, you won't notice any difference.

To make the current shell execute the command, use `source` or `.`:

```
source location.sh
. location.sh
```

Note that this `.` is a command and shouldn't be confused with the `.` folder which is an alias for the current folder.

Comment: sorry I should say, I am using the command line inside Windows to run this..
so in the command line i type and run "source HPQCscript.sh"? (the name of my script)

Comment: You need to start an interactive bash shell.  This script won't have any effect at all on your regular Windows command line.

Comment: @MarkReed how do you start an interactive bash shell?

Comment: Windows CMD doesn't support `alias`. You need a Unix-like shell for this. BASH is one of them. You can install BASH on Windows using [MinWG](http://www.mingw.org/) but you need to be aware that you start to mix Windows and Unix concepts.

Comment: @AaronDigulla i am now using a bat script

Comment: @BlueShark, if you're not using bash, your question shouldn't have the `bash` tag.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy got rid of it. was using bash but then changed after the question was written. do you know how to use control+c or control+a (copy,select all) in a script so it does it for you?

Comment: You could use a test automation robot to send keystrokes to an application but not all of them process them (for security reasons).